# I can not install I-Nex in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I can not install I-Nex in Ubuntu 16.04, I could in Ubuntu 15.10

When I run the command which I normally use to install I-Nex in terminal, it gives me a 404 error. when I try to install it via software updater it gives an error saying something about the files are not from a secure source.

Comment: It seems it still doesn't have a proper ppa for 16.04. have patience for a ppa, or try installing the generic package for Debian (not very encouraging option though, untested).

Answer (score 1):

To install I-Nex in 16.04, use these command in a Terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/daily  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```